# Как правильно работать с динамическим массивом используя for

Tags: java, android, коллекции

У меня есть массив динамический его размер может быть. 1 или 3 элемента, или 5 или 10 или 100.

Мне нужно пройтись по массиву лишь по первым 3 элементам. Если нет остальных элементов то выходим из `for`. Я не могу это реализовать. Подскажите

Мой код ужасен

```
for (int i = 0; i < mResponseList.get(0).getLessons().size(); i++) {
    if (i==3){
        break;
    }
    mResponseList.get(0).getLessons().get(i).setIsAccess(true);
}
```

Comment: Ничего прям такого ужасного в этом коде нет

Comment: @defaultlocale каждый раз использовать random access не лучшая идея же

Comment: @zTrap Действительно, не вчитывался в код, есть что улучшить. Но вопрос о прерывании цикла и `break` для этого подходит (еще бы магическое число обозвать как-нибудь осмысленно и норм). P.S. random access не проблема если используется подходящая коллекция, общую часть кода же нужно вынести в переменную

Comment: @defaultlocale Да, подходит, но это как молотком саморез забивать (в данном, простом условии прерывания цикла)

Comment: @defaultlocale в более сложных условиях без него не обойтись) Но тут можно)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int[] mArray = new int[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}; //пример массива

for(int i = 0; i < mArray.length && i <= 2; i++){
    //тут ваши действия
}
```

---

**UPD**

Базовые понятия синтаксиса цикла for:

В шапке цикла есть 3 блока (все разделяются точкой с запятой):

1. Инициализация переменных
2. Условие выполнения
3. Шаг

Все три блока (или какие либо из них) могут быть пустые

```
for(;;){

}
```

но тогда нужно урегулировать исполнение функций этих блоков в другом месте внутри цикла

---

**UPD 2**

Рефакторинг Вашего конкретного варианта:

```
List<Lessons/*Предположительное название класса*/> lessons = 
        mResponseList.get(0).getLessons();
for (int i = 0; i < lessons.size() && i <= 2; i++) {
    lessons.get(i).setIsAccess(true);
}
```

Comment: А что разве можно в for так писать? `i < mArray.length && i < 2;`

Comment: @EraNewGames дополнил ответ